Question about calculation TKNN invariant quantum ahll
In lecture note quantum hall by david tong page 61 for the calculation of berry phase, I encountered this:
$
\left| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_i} \right\rangle = -\frac{1}{L_i} \sum_{n \neq \psi_0} \frac{\langle n | J_i | \psi_0 \rangle}{E_n - E_0} | n \rangle    (1)
$
$\sigma_{xy} = i \hbar L_x L_y \sum_{n \neq \psi_0} \frac{\langle \psi_0 | J_y | n \rangle \langle n | J_x | \psi_0 \rangle - \langle \psi_0 | J_x | n \rangle \langle n | J_y | \psi_0 \rangle}{(E_n - E_0)^2}$
$= i \hbar \left[ \left\langle \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_y} \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_x} \right\rangle - \left\langle \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_x} \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_y} \right\rangle \right]
$
$
= i \hbar \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \Phi_y} \left\langle \psi_0 \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_x} \right\rangle - \frac{\partial}{\partial \Phi_x} \left\langle \psi_0 \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_y} \right\rangle \right]
$
My question is, by simply inserting equation(1) into the conductivity we should get the final result $
= i \hbar \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \Phi_y} \left\langle \psi_0 \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_x} \right\rangle - \frac{\partial}{\partial \Phi_x} \left\langle \psi_0 \bigg| \frac{\partial \psi_0}{\partial \Phi_y} \right\rangle \right]
$
But it seems to me that by inserting equation (1) we would get
$\sigma_{xy} = i \hbar L_x^2 L_y^2 \sum_{n \neq \psi_0} \frac{\langle \psi_0 | J_y | n \rangle \langle n | J_x | \psi_0 \rangle - \langle \psi_0 | J_x | n \rangle \langle n | J_y | \psi_0 \rangle}{(E_n - E_0)^2}$. How did I get this wrong?

Please define your acronyms in the title
